# Extracting data with Python from a json with different levels of nested lists and dicitonaries

Tags: python, json, extract

I have the following API to extract data from:
https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/api/internal/explore/?format=json&search=nike

I have extracted the API results using json (see below), but the structure of the API seems to be quite convoluted and I do not understand how to extract the information relevant for me and store it into a pandas dataframe. The information I am interested in are the values of the following keys

"translated_title"
"backdate"
"translated_abstract"
"translated_url"

```
r = requests.get("https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/api/internal/explore/?format=json&search=nike")
    rjson = r.json()
    users_locs = [webPage for webPage in rjson['results']]
    users_locs
```

More generally, it would be great if I could be pointed out to the logic of how to extract data from lists in a dictionary in a list in a dictionary, etc. etc.

My expected output is a dataset at a news level where for each row I report the translated title, the translated abstract and the backdate. See the following sturcture:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"translated_title" : "Chine : La pression augmente contre Nike, Apple et d’autres à mesure que le boycott lié aux allégations de travail forcé s’intensifie", "translated_abstract":'..', "backdate": "2020-07-24"}, 
{"translated_title" : "..",  "translated_abstract":'..', "backdate": ".."}])
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is you're expected output ?

Comment: Hi sushanth, I added the expected outcome, thanks for your request of clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
keys = ["translated_title", "backdate", "translated_abstract", "translated_url"]

res = [{k: x[k] for k in keys if k in x} for x in users_locs]
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Comment: @FilippoSebastio for your info `translated_abstract` has empty strings for all the records

Comment: it may be just for this api request, thanks for the solution :)